# fb.login - Iphone call from webapp doesn't work

Tags: facebook, authentication, addition

When I add my webapp to my Home on my iPhone, when Javascricpt calls `fb.login()`, the screen remains always blank.

If I don't add my webapp on my Iphone, when Javascript calls `fb.login()`, it works.

I have this problem only with my iPhone, not with my Android.

Do you know any way to resolve this problem?